# Iterate a list in a dictionary, if the list exists in the dictionary. In Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, if-statement, iteration

I have a dictionary in the following format: (In Python)

```
some_dict = {
 'some_list': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
}
```

The key 'some_list', doesn't always exist, but when it does, I want to loop its values.
To do this I'm currently doing the following:

```
if 'some_list' in some_dict:
 for value in some_dict['some_list']:
  #Run some code using value
```

Is this the best / most simple way to achive this goal, or is there a way to check for existence and loop in one line?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this. Why do you care about the number of lines?

Comment: Use `get` with default empty list `for value in some_dict.get('some_list', []):`? but I don't think it makes it any clearer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't necessarily want less lines. I just thought there might be a way to define a loop where the code knows it should skip a list when it doesn't exist, instead of raising an error.

Comment: This is also the same as mine. It's readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not wrong, anyway it can be done using [get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

```
for value in some_dict.get('some_list', []):
   #Run some code using value
```

if the key some_list doesn't exist or is empty the snippet is bypassed

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, except for the missing colon in line 2

```
if 'some_list' in some_dict.keys():
 for value in some_dict['some_list']:
  #Run some code using value
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I changed my question to include it.